# DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH mess up the order by

Tags: sql, oracle

when I create a materialize view, I use in the query an `order by` ant it works fine.
But when I refresh the MV with `DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH(('T_SEARCH', 'C')` everything is completely messed up. So is there a way to avoid that problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Can we have an example of the code?

Comment: the order define by the order by during the creation

Comment: An `order by` during the view creation is pointless overhead. The data stored in the view (or any table) has no inherent order, even if it might look like it sometimes. When you select from the view, the only way to get consistent ordering is to use an `order by` clause as part of that select, as @Álvaro G. Vicario says. See [this old question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/899514/266304) too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean that `SELECT * FROM T_SEARCH` does not provide a coherent sort order, that's the expected behaviour in all SQL dialects I know. The fact that `T_SEARCH` is not a physical table does not trigger any exception: you need to provide an `ORDER BY` clause in the `SELECT` query.