# In what order distinct clause with one column(say) displays the output in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

EMP table

```
EMPNO   ENAME   JOB       MGR   HIREDATE    SAL    COMM DEPTNO

7369    Smith   Clerk    7902   12/17/1980  800         30
7499    Allen   Salesman 7698   2/20/1981   1600    300 30
7521    Ward    Salesman 7698   2/22/1981   1250    500 30
7566    Jones   Manager  7839   4/2/1981    2975        20
7654    Martin  Salesman 7698   9/28/1981   1250   1400 30
7698    Blake   Manager  7839   5/1/1981    2850        30
7782    Clark   Manager  7839   6/9/1981    2450        10
7788    Scott   Analyst  7566   12/9/1982   3000        20
7839    King    President      11/17/1981   5000        10
7844    Turner  Salesman 7698   9/8/1981    1500        30
7876    Adams   Clerk    7788   1/12/1983   1100        20
7900    James   Clerk    7698   12/3/1981   950         30
7902    Ford    Analyst  7566   12/3/1981   3000        20
7934    Miller  Clerk    7782   1/23/1982   1300        10
```

Suppose we executed the following query on the above table:

`select distinct ename from emp;`

**Output**

```
ENAME
Ward
Turner
Adams
Allen
Martin
Blake
Clark
Scott
Ford
King
Miller
Jones
Smith
James
```

Now anyone Please explain me why Ward is displayed as output in the 1st row and not in the  order of the table output format??

Comment: Explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899514/default-row-ordering-for-select-query-in-oracle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have to specify an order

```
select distinct ename 
from emp
order by ename
```

If you don't then the DB will grab the records in the name of performance and output it unordered.

Comment: thanks juergen d for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Without ordering how you can expect ordered result.Use order by clause.