# How to select rows from Oracle as recently inserted row should be at first? (No Identity column present)

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi all
While working on Oracle I came across a situation where I need to select the rows from a table in which the recently inserted row should be at the top of my selection.
But here in my table I am not using any Identity column. I know how to do the same when there is an Identity column present, but is there any way to do this without Identity column?

Comment: Do you have some timestamp in your table.

Comment: You must have a `timestamp` column for such sorting.

Comment: Somewhat related to your question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899514/default-row-ordering-for-select-query-in-oracle

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a sequential ID or Timestamp or some other field you can `ORDER BY`, Oracle provides **no guarantee of order** and you should not rely on it.