# I am creating table in oracle database, while adding new row in auto incrementing id table its adding row before previous rows rather after

Tags: database, oracle, insert-into

I am creating table in oracle database, while adding new row in auto incrementing id table its adding row before previous rows rather than after[as in screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4yRR.png).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Default row ordering for select query in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899514/default-row-ordering-for-select-query-in-oracle)

Comment: Oracle (or any other database in general ) does not guarantee you  any specific order of rows retrieved from a select query, unless you have explicitly specified `order by` clause. So, this line is meaningless : "its adding row before previous rows rather than after"